# how to get the text after <br> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to get all the `text` after `<br/>` `tag`

my html is like this

```
<i class="loc">cherry<br>From Shimla</i>
<i class="loc">Apple<br>from kashmir</i>
<i class="loc">banana<br>From bihar</i>
```

expected output:  `["From Shimla","from kashmir","From bihar"];`

i'm trying something like this

```js
var arr = [];

$('.loc').each(function(){
   arr.push($(this).text());
});
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="loc">cherry<br>From Shimla</i>
<i class="loc">Apple<br>from kashmir</i>
<i class="loc">banana<br>From bihar</i>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target the `br` element and use `.get(index)` to fetch the underlying DOM element, the use [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) to target the text node. Then [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) property can be used to get the text.

```js
var arr = [];
$('.loc').each(function() {
  arr.push($(this).find('br').get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue);
});
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="loc">cherry<br>From Shimla</i>
<i class="loc">Apple<br>from kashmir</i>
<i class="loc">banana<br>From bihar</i>
```

You can further improve you code as

```js
var arr = $('.loc').map(function() {
  return $(this).find('br').get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue;
}).get();
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="loc">cherry<br>From Shimla</i>
<i class="loc">Apple<br>from kashmir</i>
<i class="loc">banana<br>From bihar</i>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [];

    $('.loc').each(function(){
        arr.push($(this).children('br').get(0).nextSibling);
    });
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [];

$('.loc').each(function(){
   arr.push($(this).html().split('<br>')[1]);
});
console.log(arr);
```

You can use html(), split it, and use second value from array.

```js
var arr = [];

$('.loc').each(function(){
   arr.push($(this).html().split('<br>')[1]);
});
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="loc">cherry<br>From Shimla</i>
<i class="loc">Apple<br>from kashmir</i>
<i class="loc">banana<br>From bihar</i>
```